# Are You Allowed To Eat A Fish Hamburger At McDonald's?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Are you allowed to eat a fish hamburger at McDonald's, even though they use the same oil to fry the fish hamburger, as they used to fry the bacon?

Comment: you can read here if they really fry their fishburger with the same oil as bacon http://www.mcdonalds.co.uk/ukhome/whatmakesmcdonalds/questions/food/halal/are-filet-o-fish-sandwiches-cooked-in-100-vegetable-oil-or-in-the-same-oil-as-other-meat-products.html 
i also think it differ from country to country. there are muslim countries where they serve halal meat.

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

From this [Fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/142901)

*It is permissible to eat fried meat and fish from these restaurants, subject to two conditions:*

*1.     That it is not fried in the same oil as the non-halaal chicken or in vessels in which chicken was fried, until they have been washed, because the non-halaal chicken is maytah (dead meat) and is najis (impure).*

*2.     The meat should be halaal.*

ALso have a look at this [Fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/4342)

### Allah knows best